# How to pass parameters to all the pester test scripts

Tags: powershell, pester

The `Invoke-Pester` command makes it possible to invoke a single test script with explicit parameters using the `-Script` parameter. But what if I want to pass the same parameters to all of the test scripts?
I do not want to invoke pester in a loop, because I want it to produce a single test result file.

So, how do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by passing an array of hashes to the `-Script` parameter. Something like this:

```
$a = @()
$params = @{param1 = 'xx'; param2 = 'wuauserv'}
$a += @{Path =  '.\test1.Tests.ps1'; Parameters = $params}
$a += @{Path =  '.\test2.Tests.ps1'; Parameters = $params}

Invoke-Pester -Script $a
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: The Pester docs only give an example showing a Path/Parameters hash passed to the `-Script` parameter, but most parameters and commands in Powershell seem happy to except arrays and the `-Script` excepts wildcards so I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Pester **5.1** you can use `New-PesterContainer -Data @{}` to pass all required parameters to `Invoke-Pester`.
You can pass now path to both a single test file or a test directory to `Invoke-Pester -Path`.

For instance, you have a test file:

```
param($param1, $param2)

Describe '' {
  It '' { 
    $param1 | Should -Be '...'
    $param2 | Should -Be '...'
  }
}
```

Then you run it like this:

```
$container = New-PesterContainer -Path <tests_directory> -Data @{ param1='...'; param2='...' }
Invoke-Pester -Container $container
```

The official documentation is here: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/data-driven-tests#providing-external-data-to-tests

The list of new features you can find here: https://github.com/pester/Pester/releases/tag/5.1.0

Comment: Alas, we are still on Pester 3, which is the default on our Windows. But +1